# Reach an variable array from action button clicked java

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I am stucked by coding and I need your help.

Ok first of all I have an array variable under a class.

I get the values from excel and put inside the nodename array like as follows.I shortened the following codes.

Following class Readexcel is also under ConfigGenerator Class.

```
class ReadExcel {
    private String inputFile;

    public void setInputFile(String inputFile) {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    public void read() throws IOException {
        File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
        Workbook nodes;
        try {
            nodes = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            // Get the first sheet
            Sheet nodessheet = nodes.getSheet(1);
            String[] nodename = new String[nodessheet.getRows()];
            for (int i = 1; i < nodessheet.getRows(); i++) {
                int j = 0;
                Cell x1a = nodessheet.getCell(0, i);
                nodename[j] = x1a.getContents();
                j++;
                // System.out.println(nodename[j]);
            }
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But my problem is to reaching this variable from a button action.

```
 public class ConfigGenerator extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public ConfigGenerator() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    }
        private void generateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            try {
                Writer output = null;
                for (String name: Generator.ConfigGenerator.ReadExcel.nodename[????]){
                    System.out.println(name);
                }  
                output.close();
                System.out.println("Your files has been written."); 
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ConfigGenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } 
    }
```

The parts that i added question mark is my problem for the last 2 days I am tring but couldn't get the values from that array.
First I need to get lenght of array and second the values :)
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Ok I edited the question by adding the whole section with codes.

Comment: Please post the whole class in which you read excel file, and also the class in which generateActonPerformed method is present

Comment: Please note that my button is under different Class which is called ConfigGenerator

Comment: Where is the code where you create your `ReadExcel` and `ConfigGenerator`?

Comment: Readexcel is also under ConfigGenerator added some more codes by editing question is that it that you were asking ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean that you want to get the array lenght using `nodename.length`, but I have two issues with your code:

First you access `nodename` as an array local to your `action`, then later access it as a `static` variable of class `ConfigGenerator`, which means you are accessing two different arrays.

Also, you access the `nodename` array as a `static` variable (although even the `.class` is not necessary), but you mentioned it as a "array variable" which means you need first to create a new instance of class `ConfigGenerator`, initializing the array `nodename`, and then you can use it in other classes.

Comment: yes the array called nodename is full of string variables.you're right I guess I am tring to reach it as a static but I really don't understand where should I modify in order that I can reach it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the way to retrieve the length of an array in Java is

```
nodename.length
```

not

```
nodename.getlength()
```

But you could also use the shortened syntax to loop through all elements in the specific array:

```
for (Object obj : array) {
   System.out.println(obj);
}
```

In your case it would be:

```
for (Object obj : ConfigGenerator.nodename) { //replace Object with your datatype
   System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Comment: Should i use Object or String after for ?

Comment: As you `nodename` array's type is `String[]` you can use `String` instead of `Object`.